# Getting started with XPath

Tags: java, xpath

I am self-studying XPath from *Pro XML Development with Java*. Just for practice I have constructed a sample XML document and some XPath expressions.
Below are a few XPath expressions along with their explanations and a few related questions. Please  correct me if my explanations are wrong and answer the questions wherever applicable.

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<people>
    <student scholarship="Yes">
        <name>John</name>
        <course>Computer Technology</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>

    <student>
        <name>Foo</name>
        <course>Industrial Electronics</course>
        <semester>6</semester>
        <scheme>E</scheme>
    </student>

    <grumpy-cat>
        <soup-noodle>
            <student>
                <name>Dingle</name>
                <course>Grumpiness</course>
                <semester>3</semester>
                <scheme>E</scheme>
            </student>
        </soup-noodle>
    </grumpy-cat>
</people>
```

**Expression 1:** `/people/student[@scholarship='Yes']/name`
**Explanation:** Will select the elements `<name>..</name>` which are contained in `<people>` such that `<student>` has an attribute named `scholarship` with a value of `Yes`
**Question:** Will this also select the value John in it ????

**Expression 2:** `/people/student[2]`
**Explanation:** Will select the element `<student>..</student>` which is at the 2nd position in the element `<people>`
**Question:** Will it also select the child nodes within ?

**Expression 3:** `/people/student/@scholarship`
**Explanation:** Will select the attribute scholarship in the element student. If there were multiple `<student scholarship="">` then  it would select multiple attributes

**Expression 4:** `//name[ancestor::student]`
**Explanation:** Will select all the `<name>..</name>` elements
`//` means 'all-the-descendants'. In my context it means 'I don't care who the descendants are
as long as my immediate ancestor is student'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Expression 1: `/people/student[@scholarship='Yes']/name` 
>   Explanation: Will select the elements .. which are contained in
>    such that  has an attribute named scholarship with a
>   value of Yes Question: Will this also select the value John in it ????

This expression selects any (all) `name` element that is a child of a `student` element (whose `scholarship` attribute has as string value the string "yes")and that is a child of the top element (named `people`) of the XML document. XPath doesn't select "values" -- it selects *nodes*. In this case the string "John" is the string value of the selected `name` element. The selected `name` element has a single child text node, whose string value is "John".

> Expression 2: /people/student[2] Explanation: Will select the element
>   .. which is at the 2nd position in the element
>    Question: Will it also select the child nodes within ?

This selects the second (in document order) `student` child of the top element (whose name must be `people`). The child nodes of the selected element are not selected themselves. The number of selected nodes can be obtained using the `count()` function:

```
count(/people/student[2])
```

and it is `1` -- this means that only the element (but not its children or descendants) is selected.

> Expression 3: /people/student/@scholarship Explanation: Will select
>   the attribute scholarship in the element student. If there were
>   multiple  then it would select multiple
>   attributes

This selects the `scholarship` attribute of any `student` element that is a child of the top element (whose name must be `people`). This means that if there are N `student` elements that are children of the `people` top element, and if each of these has a `scholarship` attribute, then N scholarship attributes will be selected.

> Expression 4: //name[ancestor::student] Explanation: Will select all
>   the .. elements // means 'all-the-descendants'. In my
>   context it means 'I don't care who the descendants are as long as my
>   immediate ancestor is student'

This selects all `name` elements that have a `student` ancestor (and this ancestor may not only be the immediate parent, but also an ancestor of the immediate parent).

Here one can write an equivalent XPath expression that doesn't contain any reverse axes:

```
//student//name
```

In case you wanted to select all `name` elements whose parent is a `student` element, one way to express this is:

```
//student/name
```

**Finally, I would recommend using a tool like the [XPath Visualizer](http://www.huttar.net/dimitre/XPV/TopXML-XPV.html) (which I created 12 years ago) that has helped many thousands of people learn XPath by playing and having fun**.

Comment: Would you be interested in being my mentor ? :D

Comment: @LittleChild, Yes, I hope that my answers at SO provide knowledge and advice to everyone.

Comment: Can you please recommend a light-weight XML visualization tool ? I tried `XMLEspresso` by NuBean and it sucked !

Comment: here, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520210/is-my-understanding-of-xpath-axes-correct

Answer (score 2):

All your four XPath expressions select nodes in the input tree, if you use XPath 1.0 such XPath expressions return a set of nodes (where the set can be empty or contain one or more nodes of the input tree), if you use XPath 2.0 such expressions return a sequence of nodes (which again can be empty or can contain one or more nodes of the input tree).

1. Your first expression selects one `name` element node in the given input tree, this node contains a single text node with the value `John`.
2. Your second expression selects a `student` element node in the input tree, that `student` element node has several child nodes (and XPath selection does simply select a node in the input tree, it does not modify anything or create new nodes).
3. Your third expression selects a `scholarship` attribute node, you are right that it would select several such nodes if the input XML contained several `student` element nodes with `scholarship` attributes.
4. Your fourth expression `//name[ancestor::student]` is a short form (see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) of `/descendant-or-self::node()/name[ancestor::student]` which is a short form of `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::name[ancestor::student]`. So it selects all `name` child elements of the root node as well as of all descendant nodes of the root node, where the `name` elements have a `student` ancestor element node. Your explanation of that expression is wrong, both the part about `all the descendants` (well this is at least imprecise) as well as the `my immediate ancestor is student`. The immediate ancestor is the parent, expressed simply as `parent::student` in XPath while your `ancestor::student` looks up all levels of ancestors. And all the descendants is `/descendant::name`. On the other hand with the way `//` is defined and your next step `name` the `//name` boils down to the same as `/descendant::name`.