# Is my understanding of XPath axes correct?

Tags: xpath

[image] 
I have made an info-graphic depicting the various axes in XPath. However, I am not sure as to whether they are correct.

I get confused in `following`, `following-sibling`, `preceding` and `preceding-sibling`

Is my diagram correct ?

The original image is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfgDa.jpg 
*(Taken from Pro XML Development with Java)*

Here is my understanding of the nodes I get confused in:
`descendant::` selects the nodes (element and text only) which are children and grandchildren of the context node.

`following::` selects any node (text only) which was not selected by descendant.

`following-sibling::` all the 'brothers' of the context node. That is, text and element nodes which are children of the same parent as the context node, after the context node.

`preceding::sibling` all the 'brothers' of the context node. That is, text and element nodes which are children of the same parent as the context node, before the context node.

`preceeding::` all the nodes (text only) that do not appear along the `ancestor::` axis and are not nested in any element node. (I am sure I screwed this up)

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <catalog xmlns:journal="http://www.apress.com/catalog/journal" >
        <journal:journal title="XML" publisher="IBM developerWorks">
            <article journal:level="Intermediate"
            date="February-2003">
                <title>Design XML Schemas Using UML</title>
                <author>Ayesha Malik</author>
            </article>
        </journal:journal>
        <journal title="Java Technology" publisher="IBM developerWorks">
            <article level="Advanced" date="January-2004">
            <title>Design service-oriented architecture
            frameworks with J2EE technology</title>
            <author>Naveen Balani</author>
        </article>
        <article level="Advanced" date="October-2003">
            <title>Advance DAO Programming</title>
            <author>Sean Sullivan </author>
        </article>
    </journal>
</catalog>
```

Comment: It is correct. Not a Java question, though.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik check the new image

Comment: Check out this page for a nice interactive XPath visualization http://pimpmyxslt.com/axesviz.aspx

Comment: @MadsHansen you have no idea how much that helped me.

Comment: Sorry, but you haven't provided a source XML document. I would strongly recommend *never* to use any kind of substitute for an XML document. Also see my comment to Marko Topolnik's answer -- this answer is wrong.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Check the XML

Comment: @LittleChild, As I said before, just use the XPath Visualizer and you have all your questions answered.

Comment: What tool generated that image btw? It's got `xmlns:journal=etc..` labelled as an attribute. It's not, it's a namespace declaration.

Comment: @Flynn1179 It is the tool that the authors of the book made themselves. It is called `XMLEspresso`. Available as a plug-in to Eclipse or as a standalone download

Comment: That's a little worrying.. a namespace declaration may resemble an attribute, but it's definitely not. Also, it doesn't have the right namespace anyway, the XML sample gives the namespace as `http://www.apress.com/catalog/journal`, not the w3.org address.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to gain accurate intuition about `preceding` and `following` axes is to imagine XML as a set of nested boxes or intervals, where each interval extends from the start tag to its matching end tag. In this picture you can see that any two distinct intervals *a* and *b* must be in exactly one of the following relationships:

1. *a* contains *b* (`a/descendant::b`);
2. *a* is contained by *b* (`a/ancestor::b`);
3. *a* is followed by *b* (`a/following::b`).
4. *a* is preceded by *b* (`a/preceding::b`);

If you keep to this model, you will never have a doubt in the semantics of the XPath axes.

Incidentally, this is why the tree model is bad for your intuition: it doesn't put the "nested boxes" paradigm to the forefront, so it's easy to get confused.

Comment: So, basically for `preceeding::` **all** the tags before (including nested elements and excluding attributes and namespace) the context nodes are selected ?

Comment: and for `following::`, anything which **does not** form a part of `descendant::` This only leaves out the un-nested text nodes surrounding elements :) excluding the namespace and attribute nodes that is

Comment: No, your statement is wrong. The `preceding::` axis *does not* select *all* preceding in document order nodes. This is a mistakes many people (who think they know XPath) make.

Comment: `preceeding::` selects *everything* that is **not** a part of the `ancestor::` axis

Comment: @LittleChild, Just play with the XPathVisualizer and you'll find the answers of your questions. And certainly, read a good book on XPath. As for the incorrect statement -- the `following::` and `preceding::` axes are non-overlapping with the `ancestor::` and `descendant::` axes. This is clearly specified in the W3C XPath 1.0 Spec.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev It does select all preceding nodes: this of course does not include any ancestors because the context node is *within* its ancestors, so they do not precede it. If you truly understand the document model behind XPath, you will realize that yourself.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Read the spec. -- the definition of "document order". Then you'll understand that an ancestor is preceding any of its descendants in document order. This is a quote from the spev: "*•the preceding axis contains all nodes in the same document as the context node that are before the context node in document order, excluding any ancestors and excluding attribute nodes and namespace nodes*". So, ancestors are actually preceding their descendants in document order, but of course, aren't selected by the `preceding::` axis.

Comment: Dimitre, you're confusing the opening tag with the element in it's entirety. Clearly the opening tag of any element's parent is going to precede it just as the closing tag must follow it, but not the parent element itself. That's like saying the car you're driving precedes you. The front of the car does, but not the whole car. The spec says ancestors are excluded as a clarification, not an exception, as it's logically impossible for an element to be preceded by an ancestor.

Comment: @Flynn1179, With all due respect, please, read the quote from the spec. It is not *me* -- it is the spec.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Looking at nested boxes may be helpful to *you*, but this shouldn't result in misleading the readers and contradicting the W3C XPath Spec., which is the sole normative XPath document.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I am certainly *not* contradicting anything: the semantics of my model are exactly as specified. If you don't agree, then please quote a statement from my answer that contradicts the official specification.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I see that you have edited your original answer and have removed the wrong statement. Good progress! (Naturally, I don't expect any thanks :)  )

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The concept of *document order* wasn't the point of my answer, anyway. It was many years ago that I have read those specifications and in the meantime I have substituted them in my memory with what makes sense for the model implied by the XPath axes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, The W3C XPath specification *uses* the term "document order" in the definition of the axes. Any explanation of what axes select, that omits the term "document order" has a high chance of being incorrect. I am glad that you have found a good explanation for yourself (be it correct, or not), however the only normative source about the meaning of the XPath axes still remains the W3C Recommendation for XPath 1.0.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Did I say or imply that my description was normative? My description is *useful* and *correct*. It has *teaching value*. The explanation is not for "myself" but for OP and anyone else landing on this page searching for the same explanation.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, Your initial answer certainly contained an incorrect statement. It would have remained unchanged hadn't I raised the issue. This shows that often what one considers "useful and correct" may in fact be wrong -- in case it deviates from the normative W3C source. Based on this case, I would recommend that you include a warning in any of your answers that try to explain a W3C - defined term by deviating from the official definition contained in the official source. Thus at least the reader will know not to trust 100% such deviations.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Your recommendation doesn't work for me, sorry. Maybe I should put it more clearly so you can understand my words: I inadvertently used the official term even though I did not intend to rely on its official meaning, which is why I deleted it as soon as I realized the mistake. As you can clearly see, my present answer has no need of the notice you "recommend" for me and my future answers shall follow suit.